# Displaying sums in column format with LaTeX

Tags: formatting, latex, equations

Due to my disability, I cannot write without the use of a computer. When working with numbers it is often helpful to write arithmetic problems in column format, e.g.

[image]

I have never been able to do this without assistance from an able-bodied person.

I recently began looking for a solution to this issue and found LaTeX. Is it possible to write a sum in column format in LaTeX, or is there some other more appropriate tool for this?

Note that I'm not interested in solving the sums with software, I just need to display them in a way which makes them easier for me to work with.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Wow. Didn't even know that existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use LaTeX regularly to write papers. It is a very powerful piece of software, but I'm not sure how useful it would be for your needs. Here is the minimum amount of code to write your example:

```
 \documentclass[]{article}   

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{r}
     5 \\ 
     + 12 \\ 
     \hline
     17
 \end{tabular}

 \end{document}
```

And the (cropped from A4/Letter) output:

[image]

There are some WYSIWYG editors for LaTeX such as [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) which might make it easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That looks like exactly what I was after :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the multirow package:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rr}
\multirow{2}{*}{+} & $5$ \\ 
           & $12$ \\ 
\cline{2-2}
    & 17
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]